# HLOOKUP alternative without changing table or adding row?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I'm doing some online sheet/excel tutorial and encountered a problem. My hlookup is not working because the lookup value is not in the first row of the table [HLOOKUP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuvVf.png). So I work my way around it by adding a row at the top [HLOOKUP Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODquS.png) but this doesnt look professional. Is there an **alternative function** or **way** to solve this without changing the table or adding row?

P.S. I know the answer can be seen directly but I'm preparing for a larger dataset.

Comment: You have both `excel` and `google-sheets` listed as tags, but these two platforms are very different. Please indicate which of two you are seeking an answer for by removing one of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Day,

try this one for the "Lowest Monthly Average":

> =INDEX(B1:M1,1,MATCH(B14,B12:M12,0))

and this one for the "Highest Monthly Average":

> =INDEX(B1:M1,1,MATCH(B15,B12:M12,0))

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

its done like this:

```
=HLOOKUP(B14; {B12:12; B1:1}; 2; 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of excel, then xlookup() will work.

Not sure that exists in googlesheets.